# Автомасштабирование текста в TextView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему не работает автомасштабирование в TextView?
Вроде api 28, appcompat-v7:28.+

Надо, чтобы если текст не влезает по ширине в одну линию, то он уменьшался до указанного минимального значения. Может что не так я делаю или не так понял? Андроид студия 2.3.3 у меня.

Это вообще работает у кого-нибудь? У меня просто с этими атрибутами minTextSize / maxTextSize размер текста никак не изменяется. Это вообще как работает-то? Я думал, что если одна строка текста, и текст не помещается по ширине в TextView, то размер текста будет уменьшаться до минимального указанного..

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="4sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
    android:text="Hello World! abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst "/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: в дополнение к ответу. btw, `android:textSize` не указали, у вас никогда не будет `100sp`. Возьмется указанный в теме размер, под него посчитается высота для `wrap_content` и дальше если текст не поместится, будет уменьшение размера шрифта, а вот увеличения не будет, т.к. высота просчитана уже. Если позволяет разметка, укажите максимальный `textSize` или как вариант `layout_height` явно указать достаточный вплоть до `match_parent`.

Comment: Да я какие значения не ставлю, ничего не меняется.. Мне не нужно увеличение шрифта, нужно его уменьшать если не влезает, но не работает..

Comment: С `app:autoSize*` все работает, даже в превью в Android Studio 3.5

Comment: @Alex455, кстати, на чём проверяете, где не работает? Если в дизайнере Студии 2.3.3, то она вышла задолго до этой фишки, во-первых и дизайнер, в принципе, не всё умеет правильно показывать, во-вторых.

Comment: Вроде заработало по Вашему примеру, проверяю в Genymotion, андроид 6. Вот этот код заработал, с нижнего вашего ответа: <TextView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="1"
            app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
            app:autoSizeMinTextSize="4sp"
            app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="20sp"
            app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
            android:text="Hello World!...."
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тестируете на аппарате с API меньше 26, наверное?
Если так, то атрибуты `autoSize...` не работают по причине их отсутствия.
Нужно задействовать библиотеку поддержки. Для этого в корневой элемент нужно добавить пространство имен, и заменить его у атрибутов:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
        app:autoSizeMinTextSize="4sp"
        app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
        app:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp"
        android:text="Hello World! abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst abcdefghklmnoprst "/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Как я писал выше, вроде заработало, но не работает, если добавить устаревший  android:singleLine="true", чтобы в конце текста было троеточие.. Поэтому пока остановился на библиотеке AutofitTextView, в ней все как надо работает вроде на первый взгляд.

Comment: За поведение не умещающегося текста вроде отвечает атрибут [`ellipsize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)